# Gradle dependencies: compile using local jar vs compile from maven repository?

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies

Let's say I have 2 projects: `utils-project`, `main-project`.
It works fine when I use in `main-project` `build.gradle` dependency from my maven repository:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'my.group:utils-project:some-version'
}
```

When I download jar from maven and add jar file to `build.gradle` it fails due to missing `utils-project` transitive dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('/path/to/jar/file/utils-project.some-version.jar')
}
```

How is it different and how can I achieve the same effect when compiling my main-project using local jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the Project Object Model (POM), its presence or absence. The POM file `pom.xml` contains the dependencies of a particular module and is usually deployed with the project artifacts to a Maven repository.

When you say `compile files()`, Gradle has only access to the artifact. Since the POM is absent, dependency information is not available and the build is likely to fail. In contrast, when declaring dependencies resolved from a proper repository, Gradle fetches the POM before downloading the actual artifact and its dependencies and transitive dependencies.

You can achieve the same effect with local jars by

- Downloading all dependencies and transitive dependencies (and so on) to a local folder and reference them accordingly

  ```
  compile files('/path/to/jar/file/*.jar')
  ```
- Use [flat directory repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver)
- Create a uber/fat/shaded/shadow of the particular library so that it includes all dependencies in a single `jar` file.